# Groovy assertion script is executed twice within SoapUI

Tags: testing, soap, groovy, automated-tests, soapui

Hello I'm trying to do a simple groovy script in Soapui

I try to get a testcase property and increment it then save it.
when I run then script it increments it two times I don't know why. I tried different syntaxes but nothing seems to work up to now.

Here is a screenshot that shows my problem

[image]

here I run the test 2 times, first the variable was 3, normally when I run the test the second time the before value should be at 4 and the after at 5, and not 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you do not want to have the increment logic in `Script Assertion`. 
Instead increment `counter` in the `Setup Script` of test case.

If you need the `counter` value in the script assertion, just read it alone.

Hope this helps.

By the way, I do not see any issue with script you have shown.

Check if there any where else if this variable is being manipulated.

```
def cnt = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('COUNT') as Integer
if (cnt< 10){   
    log.info "before : $cnt"
    cnt += 1
    log.info "after : $cnt"
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue('COUNT', cnt.toString())
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this script but I still get the same result !, I tried to change the variable name in my Test Steps, I tried your code, I tried different other syntaxes but none seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet. I'm seeing the same issue in 5.3.0 - here's my script that grabs a string value from properties, converts it to an Integer, increments it and sends back as a string.

```
loopsInt = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("loops").toInteger();
log.info loopsInt;
loopsInt++;
log.info loopsInt;
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("loops", String.valueOf(loopsInt));
```

I log the value before I increment, and immediately after, and as you can see, the value is being incremented twice. Here I run the script 3 times:

```
Thu Mar 16 12:04:54 NZDT 2017:INFO:52
Thu Mar 16 12:04:54 NZDT 2017:INFO:53
Thu Mar 16 12:04:56 NZDT 2017:INFO:54
Thu Mar 16 12:04:56 NZDT 2017:INFO:55
Thu Mar 16 12:04:59 NZDT 2017:INFO:56
Thu Mar 16 12:04:59 NZDT 2017:INFO:57
```

I get the same result whether I use loopsInt++ or loopsInt = loopsInt + 1. The "loops" property is not being used anywhere else. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the assertion script with the green arrow in *Script Assertion Window*, it is executed **twice**.

I have used the following script:

```
def loopsInt = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("myNum").toInteger();
log.info loopsInt
loopsInt++
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.setPropertyValue("myNum", String.valueOf(loopsInt))
```

See the following picture. One window logs even numbers and second the odd numbers.

[image]

Please note that execution in *Script Assertion Window* shall be utilized just for debugging of the script. When you execute the test case (test step), the script is executed only once, as expected.

Anyway, I think there are better places to set test case properties (setUp script, Groovy Script test step and others). I recommend to use assertion scripts for checking the message exchange.

Karel

Comment: So to test the increments you recommend me to execute the whole teststep rather than executing the script assertion ?

Comment: The Assertion script window is fine for testing the script, just be aware it's executed twice. So you need to count with different results. I assume the double execution is a SoapUI malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Found a very strange reason for this.
If the testStep having this assertion is been run successfully [i.e., if SOAP test step, then it becomes green], and after this if you open the assertion and run it separately, then it's incremented twice. Once in your editor, once within the test step itself.

Say the testSetp had failed [is red in color], then you try running the assertion separately, it works absolutely fine.